# merging dataframes with partial string matching

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, merge

I'd like to do a merge by matching only part of the string, please keep in mind that all the columns are object type and I would like to keep them that way if possible

```py
clr_null = pd.DataFrame({'Address Line': ['DUBLIN 10', 'CITY', 'DUBLIN 10 CITY']})

area = pd.DataFrame({'town': ['DUBLIN 10', 'DUBLIN 11', 'DUBLIN 12'],
                     'area': ['D10', 'D11', 'D12']})
```

I'd like to have this result:

| 'Address Line' | 'area' |
| --- | --- |
| 'DUBLIN 10' | 'D10' |
| 'CITY' | nan |
| 'DUBLIN 10 CITY' | 'D10' |

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to build an or-pattern based on `area["town"]`, then use `.str.extract` with that pattern on `clr_null["Address Line"]`, and then map the result
based on the `area` combinations:

```py
pattern = "(?i)(" + "|".join(sorted(area["town"], key=len, reverse=True)) + ")"
mapping = dict(zip(area["town"], area["area"]))
clr_null["area"] = (
    clr_null["Address Line"].str.extract(pattern, expand=False).map(mapping)
)
```

Result for the short sample:

```
     Address Line area
0       DUBLIN 10  D10
1            CITY  NaN
2  DUBLIN 10 CITY  D10
```

You have to be careful, though: regex might not be the best tool for the task (it depends on what exactly constitutes a match for your purpose). Other options are for example the `difflib.SequenceMatcher` (with `.ratio`), or, probably better, a library like [thefuzz](https://pypi.org/project/thefuzz/) (formaly known as `fuzzywuzzy`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `apply`, `loc` and `np.nan`

```
# Create emtpy area col in crl_null
clr_null['area'] = np.nan

# Function that will find partial match and set the area code
def partial_match(x, otherdf):
    otherdf.loc[otherdf[otherdf['Address Line'].str.contains(x.town) == True].index, ["area"]] =  x.area

# Apply function on area df rows and provide clr_nll df
area.apply(lambda x: partial_match(x, clr_null), axis=1)
```

`clr_nll` is now:

```
clr_null
     Address Line area
0       DUBLIN 10  D10
1            CITY  NaN
2  DUBLIN 10 CITY  D10
```